# Resistance and wattage

Tags: voltage, resistors, resistance

I have a 6 Watt LED strip.
When I turn it off it flickers briefly every 20 seconds or so.
I placed a 20 Ohm, 1/4 Watt  resistor in parallel across the connections to the LED strip and the flickering stopped.

However, when I turn the power on the resistor burns.

My power supply is 15watt and 12volts.
I don’t know what resistor I need to use, a 15 watt or a 6 watt ?

Thanks you very much and sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2):

V = I*R

R = V/I

P = I*V = V^2/R = I^2*R

You are trying to put 6W through a 1/4W resistor. Of course it burnt. Was there a reason you used 20 Ohms? Or was that just a random value?

Use those equations I posted above, and you can figure out which resistor to use, and make sure it is at *LEAST* 6W

Answer (score 1):

You need a resistor that is small enough to stop the flickering which is presumably caused by leakage from your power supply, but large enough not to be destroyed.

Power at 12V in a resistor is P = V^2/R = 144/R
Or to dissipate a given wattage you can rearrange that equation so that
Rminimum  = V^2/P
A resistor twice the Rminimum value is recommended for safety.
So for 1.w Watt and 12V
Rmin = V^2/P = 144/0.25 =~ 560 Ohms (a standard E12 value).
If a 1 watt resistor is used then Rmin can be
R = V^2/P = 144/1  ~= 150 Ohms. (Use say 330 Ohms).

However, you may find that the flickering can be prevented by a much larger value resistor - maybe 1k or even 10k.

Better still is to fix you on/off circuit so that it does not feed current to the LED strip when it is off.

Comment: I don’t really understand all your calculations but when I putted a 50ohm it was still flickering . It was underneath 22 ohm or something that it was really gone